# Echo an input of a textarea with line breaks

Tags: php

I want to echo an input of a textarea with line breaks I already try something like this to replace `<br/>` to a new line but it's not working:

```
echo '<textarea>'.nl2br('test<br/>tes2<br/>').'</textarea>';
```

The code is print the same text it's print `test<br/>tes2<br/>`

Comment: Why not just do `echo "<textarea>test\ntest2\n</textarea>";`?

Comment: The answer is on the nl2br php man page... but in short, its: `preg_replace('/\<br(\s*)?\/?\>/i', "\n", $string);`

Comment: @j08691 I think he has a string that already has `br` in it, and wants a reverse `nl2br` function.

Comment: @IncredibleHat ah, yes then if so, the regex would probably be best

Comment: @IncredibleHat really thank you it's now working with me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An answer is on the nl2br php man page in the user comments about making a reverse `nl2br` function called `br2nl`... but in short, its is simply:

```
preg_replace('/\<br(\s*)?\/?\>/i', "\n", $string);
```

You can wrap that in a minifunction and stick it in your functions toolbox for mass usage. But credit goes to the fine folks commenting on the PHP.net manual pages! http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 1):

`nl2br` function adds `br`s where newline characters (`"\n"` or `"\r"`) are in the input string. Your input string has no newline characters. Thus, it is returned unchanged.

HTML deals newline characters differently within `textarea` and `pre` tags, and in other contexts. Within `textarea` and `pre` tags newline characters do actually break the line, so it is continued on the next line. In other contexts newline characters are treated as any other space characters, i.e. all shrunk to a single space.

If your user input comes from a textarea and you output it into a textarea, then you don't need to process anything, it will be there automatically.

```
<form method="POST">
    <textarea name="text"><?= $_POST['text'] ?></textarea>
    <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Try it!

`nl2br` function exists for the case when you output the text outside of textarea:

```
<p><?= nl2br($_POST['text']) ?></p>
<form method="POST">
    <textarea name="text"></textarea>
    <button>submit</button>
</form>
```